# API response time is too slow using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, restful-url

Activity is tourist information and tag (Preference) is tag information (such as Instagram hash tag).

Function of Activity ListPreference api:
For every activity, check that each activity contains tags from the request list. Only the activities that contain the tags are serialized.

But it's too slow. It takes about 1 minute.

The api, which returns all activities, only takes 2 seconds.

What's the problem?

```
class ActivityListByPreference(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def get(self, request):
        request_tag = [6, 7, 8]
        activity_list = []
        activity_items = Activity.objects.filter()
        activity_nums=activity_items.values_list('num', flat=True)
        b=1
        for activity_num in activity_nums:
            print(activity_num)
            activity_preference_items = Activity_Preference.objects.filter(activity_num_id=activity_num)
            activity_tag = []
            preference_nums= activity_preference_items.values_list('preference_num_id',flat=True)
            activity_tag=list(preference_nums)

            intersection = set([])
            intersection = set(request_tag).intersection(set(activity_tag))
            inter_list = list(intersection)
            inter_list.sort()
            if (request_tag == inter_list):
                print('포함합니다.')
                activity_list.append(activity_num)
        activity_preference_items = Activity_Preference.objects.all()
        for activity_preference_item in activity_preference_items:
            activity_tag.append(activity_preference_item.preference_num_id)

        print('끝')
        data = Activity.objects.filter(pk__in=activity_list)
        serializer = ActivitySerializer(data, many=True)
        print(data)
        return Response({"ActivityListByPreference" : serializer.data})
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? Also, how many items (approximately) are in Activity.objects.all()?

Comment: You are doing way too many requests to your database. You are hitting it at least the number of `Activities` you have in your DB.
Could be useful to see your models `Activity` and `Activity_Preference`. It looks like to me that you are not using proper `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0):

As written, Python is making a separate database query to get `activity_preference_items` for every `activity_num` in the database.  Then the results are used to perform the filtering within Python.

To speed this up, you'll need to do more of the filtering with a smaller number of database queries.

For example, `.filter()` is lazy in Django, so you can chain multiple filters and Django will still only run one database query at the end. This can include [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), so depending on your model you will have something like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    request_tag = [6, 7, 8]
    activity_items = Activity.objects.filter()
    for request_tag_item in request_tag:
        activity_items = activity_items.filter(preference=request_tag_item)
    data = activity_items
    serializer = ActivitySerializer(data, many=True)
```